# How do I evaluate a symbol returned from a function in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, symbols, evaluation, guile

I'm refamiliarizing myself with Scheme and I've hit a problem that is probably reflecting a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

Say I do the following in Scheme (using Guile in this case but it's the same in Chicken):

```
> (define x 5)
> x
5
> (string->symbol "x")
x
> (+ 5 (string->symbol "x"))
<unnamed port>:45:0: In procedure #<procedure 1b84960 at <current input>:45:0 ()>:
<unnamed port>:45:0: In procedure +: Wrong type: x
> (symbol? (string->symbol "x"))
#t
> (+ 5 x) ; here x is dereferenced to its value 5
10
> (+ 5 'x) ; here x is not dereferenced
<unnamed port>:47:0: In procedure #<procedure 1c7ba60 at <current input>:47:0 ()>:
<unnamed port>:47:0: In procedure +: Wrong type: x
```

I understand that `string->symbol` is returning a symbol, `x`, which is effectively quoted. However, I cannot figure out how to use the symbol returned by `string->symbol` in any later context. How can I have Scheme evaluate that symbol?

To give a background on why I want to do this, it's that I'm writing a C program with embedded Guile. I would like to be able to be able to access symbols defined in Guile by name from C, using for example `scm_from_*_symbol` or `scm_string_to_symbol`. The reasons these functions aren't working the way I thought they would is related to my core question above. Perhaps there's a better way to do what I want to do with Guile, but that's a different question. Right now I'm interested in the fundamental question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the chapter [fly-evaluation](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Fly-Evaluation.html) of the Guile documentation.

You want `eval` and probably `interaction-environment`

I recommend reading the famous [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html)

Comment: `eval` did exactly what I wanted. Strange, because I tried that before but I guess I did it wrong at first. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to *evaluate* the symbol (not to "dereference" it). I think this is what you meant:

```
(define x 5)
(+ 5 (eval 'x (interaction-environment)))
=> 10
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Fly-Evaluation.html) for further details.

Comment: That don't work on Guile 2.0, because its `eval` wants *two* arguments (the thing to evaluate, and the environment....)

Comment: Doen't this example have useless evaluation of number? x is evaluated to 5 before eval is applied.

Answer (score 2):

Symbols are not special in this sense, that is they are not easier to *evaluate* than ordinary strings.

Symbol is much like a string, it just doesn't have quotes around it. Well, the fundamental difference is, of course, not absence of quotes, but the fact that symbols are *interned*. This means that strings `"x"` and `"x"` are two *different* strings (although they are equal), while symbols `'x` and `'x` are actually the same object.

Comment: Hm, then it is a fundamental misunderstanding. 
I corrected my question title to say "dereference", which is what I meant.

Comment: @BrandonInvergo Again, you really can think that symbols are string just without quotes. `(+ 5 "x")` makes no sense, so does `(+ 5 'x)`.

Comment: If you want to evaluate contents of a string as Scheme code, you don't need symbols, you need `eval-string` function.

Comment: Actually yes, it's possible to _evaluate_ a symbol.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Right, I've changed wording in my answer to be more precise.