# Setting alist with dynamically evaluated variable name in Guile Scheme

Tags: scheme, eval, guile

Currently, I have the following alist:

```
(define globals '((objects test)))
```

The name of its variable is stored in another alist:

```
(define test '((loc globals) (other properties)))
```

I would like to easily retrieve the objects list in globals. I first tried this code.

```
(assoc 'objects
       (cadr (assoc 'loc
                    test)))
```

However, that spit out an error:

> ERROR: In procedure assoc: Wrong type argument in position 2 (expecting association list): globals

I searched and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873043/how-do-i-evaluate-a-symbol-returned-from-a-function-in-scheme), so I tried using eval.

```
(assoc 'objects
       (eval '(cadr (assoc 'loc
                           test))
             (interaction-environment)))
```

However, that spit out the same error as above! Does anyone know how to call assoc with the right argument?

**EDIT (2014-10-27 21:27 EST):** Thank you for all of the solutions. Unfortunately, the submitted examples will likely not work on the full code:

```
(define-syntax object
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ name prop prop* ...)
     (begin
       (define name '(prop prop* ...))
       (let* ((parent (cadr (assoc 'loc name)))
              (objref (cdr (assoc 'objects parent))))
         (set! parent
               (assoc-set! parent
                           'objects
                           (append objref '(name)))))))))

(object my-object 
        (loc globals) 
        (name "Harry") 
        (desc "My Object"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define globals '((objects test)))    
(define test (list (list 'loc globals) '(other properties)))
; alternatively: (define test (list `(loc ,globals) '(other properties)))

(assoc 'objects
       (cadr (assoc 'loc test)))

=> '(objects test)
```

In this case, we don't want to create a list of symbols such as this:

```
'(loc globals)
```

What we want, is a list whose second element is another list called `globals`:

```
(list 'loc globals)
```

Alternatively (as pointed by Chris in the comments) we can use [quasiquoting](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html) to make explicit that we *do* want an actual value in the list, not that we forgot to quote an item:

```
`(loc ,globals)
```

**UPDATE**

This is a different problem, you should mention the whole context from the beginning. The `assoc-set!` procedure is still missing from the question, but you can try this to see if it's what you need:

```
(define-syntax object
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ name prop prop* ...)
     (begin
       (define name '(prop prop* ...))
       (let* ((parent (eval (cadr (assoc 'loc name)))) ; use Guile's eval
              (objref (cdr  (assoc 'objects parent))))
         (set! parent
               (assoc-set! parent
                           'objects
                           (append objref '(name)))))))))
```

Comment: I would actually prefer to use quasiquotation in this case (`\`(loc ,globals)`). That way, it's instantly obvious what's getting unquoted (rather than "oh, just something I forgot to quote when using `list`").

Comment: I am not sure if this will work for the full code since it uses syntax-rules and requires an arbitrary list for input. Is there some way I can easily rewrite the input list?

Comment: @Elzair please check my updated answer. Also notice that the whole syntax rule will return a void value, because the last expression being executed is `set!`, which updates a local binding. I don't know the specifics of what you're trying to implement, but seems like a good moment to reconsider your approach… this looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thank you for all your help and your advice. I updated the question with more context.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I am trying to implement an IF-development system similar to http://www.xlisp.org/zil.pdf I am trying to make it easy to define a room (or object) with the following code: (room living-room (loc rooms) (desc "Living Room") (east to kitchen) ....)

Comment: @Elzair why macros? see if using a simple procedure (perhaps with a variable number of arguments) is enough to create the data structure that you need, and simply return it at the end (so it can be assigned to a variable, etc.) as it currently stands, that `set!` part isn't doing what you think. why not return `parent`? then you'll be able to assign its value in the calling context.